# Проблема с сортировкой массива указателями

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Задача: отсортировать в обратном порядке массив через функцию. По моей задумке я передаю в функцию указатель на первый элемент массива.

Разыменовываю и сравниваю p и p+1, если p меньше, тогда меняю значения по адресам. Подскажите, где я накосячил? Реализация хоть немного похожа на правду?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n 3

void sort(int* p);
void swap(int* p1, int* p2);
void output_array(int* p);

int main()
{
    int a[n] = {1,2,3};
    sort(a);
    output_array(a);
    return 0;
}

void sort(int* p)
{
    int  box;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        for (int j=i; j<n; j++)
                if (*(p+i) < *(p+j))
                    swap(p+i, p+j);

    return 0;
}

void swap(int *p1, int* p2)
{
    int box = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = box;
    return 0;
}

void output_array(int* p)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       printf("%d", *p+i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почти все правильно, кроме `printf("%d", *p+i);` здесь надо `printf("%d", *(p+i));` (взять выражение с указателем в скобки, также как вы делали тут -- `if (*(p+i) < *(p+j))`) (ну, еще в `for (int j=i; j<n; j++)` лучше `for (int j=i + 1; j<n; j++)`)

Comment: да лааадно, о боги, сколькими способами я только не коверкал основной цикл, а проблема вообще в другом месте была...Спасибо!

Comment: И вместо `#define n 3` лучше использовать `const int n=3;`